# phpMyAdmin missing mysqli and mycrpt

Tags: mysql

I have a centos 6.2 box loaded the phpMyAdmin then I get missing mysqli then I yum install php-mysqli then I got to /etc/php.ini and put localhost under mysqli option for the host. So did I do the steps correctly? Now it gives my mcrpyt is missing? So what must I do please help ? I have tried yum install php-mcrypt but nothings to install is the message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [php-mcrypt](http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repoview/php-mcrypt.html) package is available in the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository. You'll need to configure this repository by downloading and installing the [epel-release](http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/repoview/epel-release.html) package before trying to install php-mcrypt.

Comment: how about the steps for mysqli did I do it correctly? So I have download the _64 based. So now what should I do just run the rpm command to install is it? What is this mycrpyt and its importance?

Comment: I don't know, does it work? Rather download and install the epel-release package with `rpm -i`, and then use `yum install php-mcrypt`.

Comment: ok I will try your steps the. Actually why is this mysqli and mysql difference?

Comment: mysqli is the name of a specific MySQL driver for PHP.

Comment: this mcrpyt is just for encryption right nothing more I guess. About the mysqli I adjusted the php.ini and it works that is fine right?